# NestJs: How to have Body input shape different from entity's DTO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, serialization, nestjs

I have DTOs for my Photo and Tag objects that look like this:

```
export class PhotoDto {
    readonly title: string
    readonly file: string
    readonly tags: TagDto[]
}

export class TagDto {
    readonly name: string
}
```

I use the `PhotoDto` in my `photo.service.ts` and eventually in the `photo.controller.ts` for the creation of Photo:

```
// In photo.service.ts
async create(createPhotoDto: PhotoDto): Promise<PhotoEntity> {
   // ...
   return await this.photoRepo.create(createPhotoDto)
}

// In photo.controller.ts
@Post()
async create(@Body() createPhotoDto: PhotoDto): Promise<PhotoEntity> {
   // ...
}
```

However, the input in the Body of the API is expected to have this structure:

```
{
   "title": "Photo Title",
   "file": "/some/path/file.jpg",
   "tags": [
      {
         "name": "holiday"
      },
      {
         "name": "memories"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I change the input shape of the `Body` to accept this structure instead?

```
{
   "title": "Photo Title",
   "file": "/some/path/file.jpg",
   "tags": ["holiday", "memories"]
}
```

I have tried creating 2 different DTOs, a `CreatePhotoDto` and an `InputPhotoDto`, one for the desired input shape in the controller and one for use with the service and entity, but this ends up very messy because there is a lot of work with converting between the 2 DTOs.

What is the correct way to have a different input shape from the `Body` of a `Post` request and then have it turned into the DTO required for use by the entity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the auto-transform of the `ValidationPipe()`:

1) Add the `ValidationPipe` to your controller:

```
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
@Post()
async create(@Body() createPhotoDto: PhotoDto): Promise<PhotoEntity> {
   // ...
}
```

2) Add a `@Transform` to your `PhotoDto`:

```
// Transforms string[] to TagDto[]
const transformTags = tags => {
  if (Array.isArray(tags)) {
    return tags.map(tag => ({name: tag}))
  } else {
    return tags;
  }
}


import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
export class PhotoDto {
    readonly title: string
    readonly file: string
    @Transform(transformTags, {toClassOnly: true})
    readonly tags: TagDto[]
}
```

Comment: For some reason, my nested dto passed as POST body becomes to string instead of Class contains another Class. The seconds `@Transform` solution really saved me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update DTO to

`export class PhotoDto {
    readonly title: string
    readonly file: string
    readonly tags: Array<string>
}`

It will change the API structure to

`{
   "title": "Photo Title",
   "file": "/some/path/file.jpg",
   "tags": ["holiday", "memories"]
}`

currently your tags property is an array of object of type **TagDto**, change tags property to just array of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `nest` custom decorator to convert input data to your DTO object.

```
export const ConvertToCreateCatDto = createRouteParamDecorator((data, req): CreateCatDto => { // `createParamDecorator` for nest old version
    if (req.body.tags.every(value => typeof value === "string")) { // if input tags is a string[]
        req.body.tags = (req.body.tags as string[]).map<TagDto>((tag) => {
            return { // convert to TagDto
                name: tag + ""
            }
        });
    }
    let result = new CreateCatDto(req.body);
    // TODO: validate `result` object
    return result;
});
```

add constructor to CreateCatDto

```
export class CreateCatDto {
    readonly title: string;
    readonly file: number;
    readonly tags: TagDto[];

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.title = obj.title;
        this.file = obj.file;
        this.tags = obj.tags;
    }
}
```

Finally, use `@ConvertToCreateCatDto` instead of `@Body` in you controller.

```
// In photo.controller.ts
@Post()
async create(@ConvertToCreateCatDto() createPhotoDto: PhotoDto): Promise<PhotoEntity> {
   //...
}
```