# Best way to sanitize nest request

Tags: nestjs

I created DTO and schema to create an entity by using POST method.
Some of the data will be only initial and I want to prevent fill it by user request.

What's is the best way to sanitize requests (maybe using only DTO - e.g. decorators?)

```
export class CreateActionDto {
    userId: string;
    isActive: boolean = false;
}
```

^^ in this case I'd like to remove isActive from a user request (should be always false after create).
Thanks.

Comment: you can just remove the `isActive` from DTO and set your entity's `isActive` default value as `false`. To prevent it, i think you have to extract the required fields manually

Comment: you can extract the fields using a `pipe`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NestJs: How to have Body input shape different from entity's DTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55448050/nestjs-how-to-have-body-input-shape-different-from-entitys-dto)

Comment: But if I remove fields from DTO, typescript will report an issue when I'll try to create a new entity: await this.actionModel.create(createActionDto)

Comment: Okay, I found solution: I need to create DTO with optional TS properties & next use whitelisting: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#stripping-properties